# Extract images of signatures contained in a pdf file with iTextSharp library

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have a signed PDF file. With this function, which makes use of iTextSharp library, I find the certificates p7m signatures:

```
        private void GetSignature(string FileName)
    {
        AcroFields acroFields = new PdfReader(FileName).AcroFields;
        List<string> names = acroFields.GetSignatureNames();

        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            PdfDictionary dict = acroFields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
            PdfString contents = (PdfString)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dict.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS));

            byte[] PKCS7 = contents.GetOriginalBytes();
            ByteArrayToFile(@"c:\signature\" + name + ".p7m", PKCS7);

        }
    }
```

Now... how can I extract images (bitmap) associated to the signatures? Is it possible?
Thanks, Luigi

Comment: If you are sure that it is merely a bitmap, it is not too difficult to extract it. But in the wild there pretty often non-bitmap graphics and text are also part of the visualization.  That would be asking for rendering PDF parts to image, and that's not yet implemented in itext.

Comment: It's not a simple image... otherwise I would have extracted. Substantially the signature is composed of a certificate, a picture and a package of biometric data (speed, pressure and acceleration).

Comment: Please provide a sample file. There is no need for biometric data in a digital signature as authentication here uses certificates and asymmetric encryption.

Comment: Yuo can find the file here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2303720/signSample.pdf

Comment: Ah, signatures created with xyzmo software... They used to sign using their completely own PDF objects. Judging by the sample you provided they now have at least started using standard signatures as foundation of their signing technology. Still they include their own information in an added object referenced as **/xyzmo_signature** from the **/Sig** dictionary. I think you will have to ask the xyzmo people how to interpret their custom data added to the signature, especially as most of its content is in an XML **EncryptedSignatureDataContainer** fragment...

Comment: I added an analysis of the data contained in your sample document as an answer. If you are interested in the details of extracting any of them, tell me which. I'll extend the answer accordingly. I would use Java code, though, as I hardly ever do c#. But translation should be easy.

Comment: Thanks, I added a comment below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your sample documents the term *signature* applies threefold:

1. It contains digital signatures according to the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).
2. The respective visualization contains a bitmap image of an handwritten signature.
3. The respective signature dictionary contains proprietary information by the software which added all the signature data to the PDF. Most likely these proprietary information contain the biometric data mentioned in the comments of the OP.

According to the manufacturer of the software creating these multi-level signatures, the handwritten signature seems like the major proof of identity. The digital one only serves to protect the document from changes; it does *not necessarily* reflect the identity of the person who signed manually but instead of the owner of the device on which that manual signature was created ("Please sign here that you got the parcel"):

> **Functions**
>
> **Handwritten Signature Capturing** - Forensically identifiable signatures on signature pads, payment terminals, the iPad or Android devices.
>
> **Signature Verification** - Compare a handwritten signature against a pre-enrolled profile.
>
> **Control all steps in the signing process** - Including positioning signature fields, filling out forms, adding annotations, adding attachments, and much more.
>
> **Protects the Integrity of Documents** - By sealing them with a digital signature.
>
> *([xyzmo English website start page](http://www.xyzmo.com/en/Pages/xyzmostart.aspx))*

Concerning the extraction of all these information using iText...

1. The properties of the digital signature can easily be extracted and verified as already observed by the OP using the signature related methods of the `AcroFields` class.
2. The bitmap image of the handwritten signature can also be extracted fairly easily. The appearance stream of the signature form field dictionary merely paints that bitmap which is attached to the stream as a resource.
3. The data container containing the proprietary information can also be extracted as it is the value of just another key in the signature dictionary.
4. Unfortunately, though, the *contents* of that data container are packed into a XML fragment calling itself **EncryptedSignatureDataContainer**. Whether the payload data of this XML fragment can be properly *decrypted* and how it is to be interpreted is information to request from the xyzmo people themselves, and I have no idea if they consider that information public or not.

Thus, the most relevant information is the least accessible one.

**PS** Concerning the decryption of the encrypted biometric payload I found the following on the manufacturer's website:

> The document contains a captured signature that has been encrypted (RSA 4096 + AES256). A person’s signature is encrypted immediately as it is captured by the signature pad, using the private key of a special certificate. This special certificate is selected by the company using the xyzmo suite, and is typically stored in a secure environment outside the company (bank safe, external notary, etc.). Thus, xyzmo itself has NO access to this certificate. For the encryption of signatures, the xyzmo suite just needs the public key of the certificate. It is only for decryption, and the extraction of signatures from a document, that the private key is required. Only specific people, to whom the company has granted access to this certificate, will be able to decrypt the profile using the PenAnalyst tool, which is provided as part of the suite.
>
> *([xyzmo English website Digital Signature Capture FAQ's](http://www.xyzmo.com/en/resource-center/Pages/DigitalSignatureFAQ.aspx))*

Thus, to decrypt the biometric data you have to have access to the respective private key which *is typically stored in a secure environment outside the company (bank safe, external notary, etc.).* If you have that kind of access, we may continue talking about the format of those decrypted data... ;)

BTW, if anyone could simply retrieve the biometric data from the signed document, they could too easily be copied to other documents to fake a signature.

**Extracting the bitmap image of the handwritten signature**

As there was special interest in the extraction of the bitmap image of the handwritten signature, here a quick and dirty helper to extract the image of the signature. As already said, I do it in Java as I'm more at home there:

```
public class XyzmoSignatureDataExtractor
{
    public XyzmoSignatureDataExtractor(PdfReader reader)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public PdfImageObject extractImage(String signatureName) throws IOException
    {
        MyImageRenderListener listener = new MyImageRenderListener();

        PdfDictionary sigFieldDic = reader.getAcroFields().getFieldItem(signatureName).getMerged(0);
        PdfDictionary appearancesDic = sigFieldDic.getAsDict(PdfName.AP);
        PdfStream normalAppearance = appearancesDic.getAsStream(PdfName.N);

        PdfDictionary resourcesDic = normalAppearance.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
    
        PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(listener);
        processor.processContent(ContentByteUtils.getContentBytesFromContentObject(normalAppearance), resourcesDic);        

        return listener.image;
    }

    class MyImageRenderListener implements RenderListener
    {
        public void beginTextBlock() { }

        public void endTextBlock() { }

        public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                image = renderInfo.getImage();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failure retrieving image", e);
            }
        }

        public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

        PdfImageObject image = null;
    }

    final PdfReader reader;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resourceStream);
XyzmoSignatureDataExtractor extractor = new XyzmoSignatureDataExtractor(reader);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();

for (String name: acroFields.getSignatureNames())
{
    System.out.printf("\nTesting signature '%s'.\n", name);
    PdfImageObject image = extractor.extractImage(name);

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("target/test-outputs/SampleXyzmoSignature-image-" + name + "." + image.getFileType());
    os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
    os.close();

    PdfDictionary imageDictionary = image.getDictionary();
    PRStream maskStream = (PRStream) imageDictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.SMASK);
    if (maskStream != null)
    {
        PdfImageObject maskImage = new PdfImageObject(maskStream);

        os = new FileOutputStream("target/test-outputs/SampleXyzmoSignature-image-" + name + "-mask." + maskImage.getFileType());
        os.write(maskImage.getImageAsBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

**Warning:** The class `XyzmoSignatureDataExtractor` really is a quick&dirty hack. Many assumptions are made, `null`-checks are left out, ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
With reference to the point 2, when you talk about:
_"The bitmap image of the handwritten signature can also be extracted fairly easily."_ 
could you provide me the code to extract singles signatures bitmap.
I've tried to use the method `ExtractImages(filename)` of this [class](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2303720/ImageExtractor.cs) to extract the images from pdf, but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Your `PdfImageExtractor` extracts images contained in or referenced from the content stream of the page. The signature images at hand, though, are referenced from the normal appearance stream of the signature annotation. I added some quick&dirty Java code to the answer to show how to extract such images.

Comment: Thank you very much... it works perfectly!
Your advise has been very useful.
All the best.

Comment: If you are interested in a .Net/iTextSharp version, @user3492925 ported the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38432345/1729265).