# What tool or library can check if PDF have biometric signature data

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, signing, biometrics

My goal is to sign PDF and embed signature biometric data.
I'll try to use https://github.com/biosignin/bsi-core for converting raw biometric data to ISO/IEC 19794-7:2007 format.

Is there any tool or library that I could use to check if new PDFs are having biometric data embedded correctly?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any tool or library that I could use to check if new PDFs are having biometric data embedded correctly?

Unfortunately there does not yet seem to be a way to **do that correctly**.

The current [PDF standard](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) ISO 32000-1 does not specify a standard way to embed biometric data. In it you find the word "biometric" but once: *The signature may be purely mathematical, such as a public/private-key encrypted document digest, or it may be a biometric form of identification, such as a handwritten signature, fingerprint, or retinal scan* in section 12.8.1 (Digital Signatures / General).

ISO 19794-7 does not present a specific way to embed biometric data in PDFs either. On the contrary:

> It is advisable that cryptographic techniques be used to protect the authenticity, integrity, and confidentiality of stored and transmitted biometric data; yet such provisions are beyond the scope of this part of ISO/IEC 19794.
>
> *(section 1, visible in the ISO 19794 [preview](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec19794-7%7Bed2.0%7Den.pdf))*

You might want to look at existing solutions and analyze their way of doing it. You can find my first impressions of the xyzmo way in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17402565/1729265).