# Attach biometric data from Wacom STU SDK to a PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, signature, biometrics, wacom

I need to implement Wacom tablet handwriting in my Java software and I'm using the STU SDK for Linux.

In the samples that are present in the SDK it is shown how to acquire the PenData and transform them into an image but for legal purposes I am forced to also attach the biometric data (pressure, timing) together with the image of the signature in the PDF document.

Is there a correct way or format to attach this biometric data in a PDF document?

For PDF document management in my software I use iTextPDF and Apache PDFBox.

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know there is no common standard for integrating that data in a PDF. Some thoughts, though: To make any sense, those data need to be stored in a way that is cryptographically bound to the PDF in question. And it must be made sure that most of the data can only be read upon request of the authorities - if anyone could read them, anyone could copy them and store them as a signature of a different document. 
There may be more requirements; as you mention legal purposes, there likely is a legal framework for those signatures enumerating requirements.

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17402565/1729265) I ten years ago superficially analyzed a PDF signature by xyzmo (now Namirial) that also stored a combined biometric/digital signature, so you might find the information there interesting. Unfortunately the links in that answer to the xyzmo web site don't work anymore.